# Find the equation of an ellipse in a complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find an equation for the ellipse that passes through $3+7i$ if its foci at $i$ and $-1$.
This is what i have so far.
I know that the equation of an ellipse is $|z-p| + |z-q| = c$. so $|z-p| + |z-q| = \sqrt{(3)^2 + (7+1)^2} + \sqrt{(3)^2 + (7-1)^2} = \sqrt{73} + \sqrt{45} = 15.25$ Now, i think the equation is $|z-i| + |z-(-i)| = 15.25$.
Is that correct?